# OpenerDirector.open() Время ожидания загрузки страницы

Tags: python

Привет. С помощью opener хожу по ссылкам и иногда попадаю на большие файлы, которые начинают качаться:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.open('site.ru/file.exe' timeout=2)
```

Timeout не помогает прерывать такие загрузки. Как можно реализовать иначе прерывание ожидания полной загрузки страницы?

Answer (score 1):

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()

def url_reader(url, lim=1024*500):
    """
    Первым аргументом функция принимает урл. Вторым -
    предельный размер файла в байтах. По умолчанию 500 килобайт.
    Если файл окажется не слишком большим, функция вернёт
    считанные данные. В противном случае - None.
    """
    # Получаем заголовки с урла.
    response = opener.open(url)
    if response.headers.get("Content-Length", 0) > lim:
        # если в хедерах сказано, что файл здоровый, верим хедерам и уходим.
        print "File %s is too big" % url
        return None
    # НО! Это не всё. Иногда хедеры преуменьшают размер,
    # а иногда размер файла просто не указывается.
    # Такое бывает при жёстком редиректе, например.
    # Код под этим ифом дублирует предыдущий.
    # Просто чтобы не путать тебя ЭНДами.
    # 
    # Считываем столько данных, сколько нужно.
    data = response.read(lim)
    if len(data) == lim:
        print "File %s is too big" % url
        return None
    return data
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за то что ответили. К сожалению скачивание не прерывается потому чтоresponse = opener.open(url)